# how to choose a custom layout by name language independent

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I already implemented a method which takes the name of the needed layout, iterates through all the custom layouts and gives the layout back as soon as the name is found.
Unfortunately the name changes when the user uses Office in a different language.
The question is what translates the custom layout names and how can I use the same translation within my VBA code?
Any ideas?

Comment: I've created many foreign-language PowerPoint templates and have never observed custom layout names changing when a presentation is moved to a new computer. The built-in layout names are different in a new file, perhaps that's what you've seen?

Comment: After reviewing my code I found, that not the layouts I create during runtime cause the problems, it´s the standard layouts which are contained in the template provided by the company. There we have layouts named like "Title Slide double-spaced" and it´s that namings which cause problems when the user uses a different office UI (and document) language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard layouts in a new blank presentation have different names in different languages, but you don't need to identify them by name. Each standard layout can be identified with SlideLayout.Type. Here's is Microsoft's enumeration of these: [PpSlideLayout enumeration (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppslidelayout). These are language independent.

Custom Layouts that you create will all have the Custom layout type. But their names won't change, so you won't have an issue with them.